# Signing and Verifying Messages in Ethereum

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am trying to follow this [tutorial here](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/17/signing-and-verifying-messages-in-ethereum/):

But in the tutorial he doesnt specify how to implement the contract. So I tried to do it using truffle and ganache-cli. In a truffle test I have tried using the following code:

```
const amount = web3.toWei(5, 'ether');
const Contract = await GmsPay.new({from : Sender, value : web3.toWei(10, 'ether')});
const hash = Web3Beta.utils.soliditySha3(
    {t : 'address', v : Recipient},
    {t : 'uint256', v : amount},
    {t : 'uint256', v : 1},
    {t : 'address', v : Contract.address}
);
const sig = await Web3Beta.eth.sign(hash, Sender);
const res = await Contract.claimPayment(amount, 1, sig, {from : Recipient});
```

But I just keep getting, "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert". Using the debuger I see that my code executes down to:

```
require(recoverSigner(message, sig) == owner);
```

Even if I take that line out the last line still doesnt work. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're not funding the contract with any ether, so that probably explains why the transfer fails even if you remove the signature check. Double check that `claimPayment` is being called by `recipient` and that you're signing with the right account. (Is `Sender` the `owner` account?)

Comment: Sender is the owner of receiverPays, How do I set claimPayment to be called by recipient?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Truffle, but I assume `await Contract.claimPayment(amount, 1, sig, { from: recipient });`

Comment: That got the transfer to work but that one require line still fails, I updated the code as well to reflect those two other changes you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into similar challenges in my truffle tests with the 'recoverSigner(message, sig) == owner' check. After comparing R,S,V, values produced in the solidity recoverSigner() function vs. the same values generated on the test side using the ethereumjs-util's fromRpcSig() function, I realized that recoverSigner is returning V as a 0, whereas fromRpcSig has this value at 27. [This line](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/153b7c35dbd275067d04ba42773aeefcdf99377d/src/index.ts#L416) provided the working answer.

Final splitSignature() function included below if you run into a similar issue.

```
function splitSignature(bytes memory sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (uint8, bytes32, bytes32)
    {
        require(sig.length == 65);

        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;
        uint8 v;

        assembly {
            // first 32 bytes, after the length prefix
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))
            // second 32 bytes
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))
            // final byte (first byte of the next 32 bytes)
            v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }

        // support both versions of `eth_sign` responses
        if (v < 27) 
            v += 27;

        return (v, r, s);
    }
```